# how to access and return a variable value from outside a function

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, promise

Basically I have a loop where I find an url in an api, then I need to return it and use it outside of the loop, in order to return it to the client.

but im not able to access **urlFinal** from outside of the loop..

this the code

```
let urlFinal

const bucle = setInterval(function () {
    console.log('antes de Axios')
    axios
    .get(url, {
        headers: { Authorization: AuthorizationWompi },
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log('Then antes de If')
        if (response.data.data.payment_method.extra.async_payment_url) {
        urlFinal =
            response.data.data.payment_method.extra.async_payment_url
        clearInterval(bucle)
        console.log('al final del if')
        }
    })
}, 1000)

console.log(urlFinal)

return {
    statusCode: 200, // <-- Important!
    body: JSON.stringify({
        id: transaccion,
        link: urlFinal,
    }),
}
```

Comment: Where is the loop and where is the function ?

Comment: the loop is the setinterval, the function is just the anonymous function. the whole thing is inside a case of aswitch.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is because the value of `urlFinal` may not be assigned when you want to use it since it takes time for the asynchronous part of your code to assign value to it. You can do something like this...

```
const bucle = setInterval(function () {
    console.log('antes de Axios')
    axios
    .get(url, {
        headers: { Authorization: AuthorizationWompi },
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log('Then antes de If')
        if (response.data.data.payment_method.extra.async_payment_url && typeof response.data.data.payment_method.extra.async_payment_url !== 'undefined') {
        useUrlFinalOutside(response.data.data.payment_method.extra.async_payment_url)
        clearInterval(bucle)
        console.log('al final del if')
        }
    })
}, 1000)

function useUrlFinalOutside(urlFinal){
  // your code that uses urlFinal
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just tried it but when I tried to return urlFinal it is undefined.  I tried like this function useUrlFinalOutside(urlFinal) {
            // your code that uses urlFinal
            return {
              statusCode: 200, // <-- Important!
              body: JSON.stringify({
                id: transaccion,
                link: urlFinal,
              }),
            }
          }

Comment: I think this might be because the value you pass as urlFinal is undefined. I added the check in the if clause too.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need a setInterval.

You can use `async function` with `await`.

Set a while loop and when you get a response, you can break the while loop.

I also use a `delay` function to delay each API call not to utilizes the program.

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function run() {
  let urlFinal;
  while (true) {
    console.log("antes de Axios");
    const response = await axios.get(url, {
      headers: { Authorization: AuthorizationWompi },
    });
    const asyncPaymentUrl =
      response?.data?.data?.payment_method?.extra?.async_payment_url;
    if (asyncPaymentUrl) {
      console.log({ asyncPaymentUrl });
      urlFinal = asyncPaymentUrl;
      break;
    }

    await delay(3000);
  }

  const obj = {
    id: transaccion,
    link: urlFinal,
  };

  return {
    statusCode: 200, // <-- Important!
    body: JSON.stringify(obj),
  };
}

run().then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. but it still returns undefined .. the reason that I had the setInterval Loop was because in the begining the api doesnt provide the extra field, but after a few mili seconds it provides the extra field..

Comment: @DavidGarcia, I updated my answer. I log the `asyncPaymentUrl ` once you receive it. Please let me know if you receive it in the console. The logic actually is check every 3 seconds if you can get a responses that contains a `async_payment_url`, if so, it will return, otherwise it will not return until it get the `async_payment_url`.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'async_payment_url' of undefined -> I get this in Console.

Comment: @DavidGarcia, Thanks for your reply. I made a mistake. I now add optional chaining `?.` and please try again.